# Read-only SQL account: what can you do?

Tags: sql, database, security

Context: I am not a professional engineer. I work for a government unit and I am pretty much **the** tech-quant-data guy in our little group.

I want to request for an sql database account from a different IT unit so I can pull data directly without requesting from anyone. I only intend to have read-only privilege. Some columns will also be restricted as they contain personal information that I have no business having.

I will be using the database account in Python scripts probably in my own computer to pull data from their databases.

**My concern is regarding security on their end. What can a malicious IT person reasonably do with a read-only SQL account?** The data is fundamentally just demographic stats. Assume that the data accessible to the account are not exactly sensitive, but should also not be freely distributable, and should also under no circumstance be tampered with. I have near zero familiarity with internet security.

I understand that for webpages, SQL creds are hidden in PHP so you can't just look at the source as a user. But does the security concern exist if the account is only read only? I don't want the organization to be hacked. I don't know DBA best practices.

Thanks!

*edited for clarity

Comment: What do you want to do and what is your problem?

Comment: Which SQL database? SQL is a _language_, implemented by dozens of products.

Comment: @MeyssamToluie i want to request for an sql account from the IT unit with read-only privilege. i am looking to know about any security concern on their end that might make my idea unrealistic and even stupid.

Comment: @jarlh i suppose i am asking in general, independent of any sql database. will there be different concerns based on which sql implementation they use?

Comment: hello! edited the post for more clarity, hopefully.

Comment: Since I don't know all different product I can't tell the difference. However, except for exporting data, I'd ask myself if a read-only user can ask very heavy queries, like an overload attack.

Comment: @user56833 Before posting a question, determine what problem do you want to solve? I understand your concern, but why do you want to ask for a permission? First of all list your activity and search for required permission. Then ask from the IT team the listed permission.

Comment: @jarlh this is informative thanks! I found Resource Governor for SQL Server and Resource Manager for Oracle. naive queries that can hog resources/crash is definitely a risk. I'm sure the IT unit can make a procedure to limit the size of my queries.

Nobody has mentioned any grave security concern so I take that as good!

Comment: @MeyssamToluie I suppose I am more looking for problems caused by my idea? I am not a DBA so I dont know the risks involved with giving some other non IT office a read-only database account. I dont want to find out 6 months from now, someone found a loose post-it and destroyed our database.